# Should Postfix run chrooted if it already is in it a FreeBSD jail?

Tags: postfix, freebsd, dovecot, chroot, jail

I'm running Postfix together with Dovecot and a few milters in a FreeBSD jail.

Is there a significant security gain when I run SMTP and SMTPD daemons chrooted  as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jail is already a chrooted environment so you can't gain more benefits chrooting jailed software.